# Symfony 3 JWT Token Authentication Error with User Provider

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, jwt, provider

I have a Problem with my JWT Token Authentication. I am pretty new in Symfony and if I add an User Provider to my User Entity the Token Authentication doesn't work and you don't need a token in the header anymore => Access to anything. But if I remove the User Provider I get this message on every second request but the other request works fine with the token:

```
"There is no user provider for user "AppBundle\Entity\TbluserBase"
```

Can someone help me please or suggest some tutorials for this problem? I think I am missing or have to change something in my securtiy file.

JWT Authenticator

```
class JWT_Authenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator {

private $Entity_Manager;
private $JWT_Encoder;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em, DefaultEncoder $jwt_Encoder) {
    $this->Entity_Manager = $em;
    $this->JWT_Encoder = $jwt_Encoder;
}

public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null) {
    $error = ['error' => 'Auth header required'];
    return new JsonResponse($error, 401);
}

public function getCredentials(Request $request) {
    if (!$request->headers->has('Authorization')) return;

    $extractor = new AuthorizationHeaderTokenExtractor(
        'Bearer',
        'Authorization'
    );

    $token = $extractor->extract($request);
    if(!$token) return;

    return $token;
}

public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $user_Provider) {
    $data = $this->JWT_Encoder->decode($credentials);
    if (!$data) return;

    $username = $data['usrnickname'];

    $user = $this->Entity_Manager
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:TbluserBase')
        ->findOneBy(['usrnickname' => $username]);
    if (!$user) return;

    return $user;
}

public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user) { return true; }

public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
    return new JsonResponse([
        'message' => $exception->getMessage()
    ], 401);
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey) { return; }

public function supportsRememberMe() { return false; }

}
```

Security

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 15
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 15
        AppBundle\Entity\TbluserBase:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 15
        harsh:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 15
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        base_users:
            id: app.user_provider
    firewalls:
        api:
            pattern: ^/api/(?!Get_Token)
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - app.jwt_token_authenticator
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
            #http_basic: ~

            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
            #form_login: ~
    access_control:
        - { path: /api/Get_Token, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_API_USER] }
```

Services

```
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

services:
    app.user_provider:
        class: AppBundle\Security\UserBaseProvider
    app.jwt_token_authenticator:
        class: AppBundle\Security\JWT_Authenticator
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder.default']
        #service_name:
    #    class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
    #    arguments: ['@another_service_name', 'plain_value', '%parameter_name%']
```

User Provider

```
class UserBaseProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $user = new TbluserBase();
        $user->setUsrnickname($username);
        return $user;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $user;
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class == 'AppBundle\Entity\TbluserBase';
    }

}
```

I worked with these tutorials:

https://kolabdigital.com/lab-time/symfony-json-web-tokens-authentication-guard

https://de.slideshare.net/weaverryan/symfony-guard-authentication-fun-with-api-token-social-login-jwt-and-more

Comment: Can you post the code of your `AppBundle\Security\UserBaseProvider` class?

Comment: Updated and added